# jQuery Datepicker highlight selected date after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, datepicker

I am trying to have jQuery Datepicker keep the selected date highlighted after page reload, instead of highlighting todays date.

When a date is clicked it reloads the page to itself and passes a hidden field value that loads records based on the date value. The form is processed with Coldfusion and the hidden field contains the date being selected.

How do I pass the hidden field date value, "passDate", into datepicker to highlight the selected date in the calendar after the page reloads?

```
$(function() {          
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",

    onSelect: function (dateText) {
      var dateAsString = dateText;

      $('#passDate').val(dateAsString);

      $('#date_calendar').submit();               
   }
});


<div id="datepicker">
    <form id="date_calendar" method="post" action="">
        <input type="hidden" name="passDate" id="passDate" >
    </form>
</div>
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: Get the submitted date on the server and echo it as the selected date for the datePicker. As we don't even know what serverside language you're using, it's kinda hard to write an answer ?

Comment: I should have added the form is processed with Coldfusion.

Comment: I don't really know any coldfusion, but this is basically the concept

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4G7AF/

Comment: Thanks for reply but that didn't really work. I don't think knowing how the form is processed on the server side matters since I am grabbing the value in jQuery above. Any other help appreciated.

Comment: But you're reloading the page, so you have to store the date somewhere. You could use localStorage, but you already have the date on the serverside so you just have to output it somewhere.